# In the carrom last turn red coin mine black coin and opponent white coin

Tags: carrom

On the board there are the red coin (queen), my black coin and my opponent's white coin. The opponent pockets the red queen first and next pockets the white coin, but accidentally pockets the striker also.

What happens? Is the game over (who wins), or something else?

Answer (score 2):

From the [International Carrom Federation rules](https://www.iakc.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Carrom-Official-Rules.pdf)

> 101. a) While covering the Queen by a proper stroke, if a player pockets the striker along with his C/m, the C/m so pocketed plus one C/m as Due shall be taken out for placing by the opponent. The player shall however, continue his turn. If in that subsequent stroke no C/m of the player is pocketed, the Queen shall not be considered to have been covered and it shall be taken out for placing.

So: return the white coin and an extra white coin as due, and the player gets another attempt to try and cover the queen.